# C++ Macro defined from outside .cpp or .hpp

Tags: c++, macros, cmake

I want to do something like an application that is build in debug or release mode.

Is it possible to define a macro outside the .cpp or .hpp?

I am using CMake. I have seen that `add_definitions(...)` is doing something like this. Shall I create two executables `proj` and `proj_debug` and for debug define a macro with `add_definitions(...)`? Is this a good approach? If not, how would you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man g++ http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

Look for the -D option for defining macros

and you can configure your makefiles to set that option http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Dxxxx")
```

Comment: This worked for me, but doing `cmake -Ddebug ..` in command-line and with an `if(debug) set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -DDEBUG") else() set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall") endif()` comand. Thanks

Comment: For CMake v2.8.11 onwards, [Steve's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23092271/2556117) is the correct one.  Failing that, `add_definitions` is probably more appropriate than updating the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
target_compile_definitions(myproj PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:MY_DEBUG_MACRO>)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

This works with all generators and is the documented, right, supported way of doing it (and implemented by me :) ).

Comment: When I write this command it says `Unknown CMake command "target_compile_features".` Why? Should I put it not in the cmake file?

Comment: Then you need to update to use CMake 2.8.11 or later :)

Answer (score 1):

To define Macro in the different file can be done by following ways:

1) You can define Macro in any other `.h` file.
   and include the file in `.cpp` file.
   This can help you to define Macro in different file
   To check the Macro for `Debug and Release` version use `_Debug` or `_Release` Macro.

2) Another way to do this is By using the way told by @Soren.
   using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Dxxxx")`

Answer (score 0):

> like this. Shall I create two executables proj and proj_debug and for debug

No need.

With cmake you can change the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable when configuring your project. Then in your `CMakeLists.txt` you can do something like:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    add_definitions(-DMY_DEBUG_MACRO)
endif()
```

Then you can easily configure your project twice (in two directories): once with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` set to `Debug` and once `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` set to `Release`.

Comment: Querying CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not portable. Your suggestion would only work for Makefile and Ninja generators, not the IDE generators.